# Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I want my cakephp support Unicode, I have tried to change my database config (`cakephp-2.3.2/app/Config/database.php`)

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '***************',
    'database' => 'db_1stcakephp',
    'prefix' => '',                
    'encoding' => 'utf8' // I applied this statement to make cake php support unicode;
);
```

After that I refreshed my site and what I got is an error occurred:

> Error: Undefined class constant '**MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND**'  File:
>   C:\wamp\www\cakephp-2.3.2\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\Database\Mysql.php
>   Line: 146

Comment: Make sure your `php_pdo_mysql` extenstion is enabled.

Comment: Yes, it's enabled already; then what should I do?

Comment: Seems `[driver] => mysql` is missing in your array,can you check adding it in.

Comment: Can you please detail me more clearly? Because I'm very new with cakephp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined class constant 'MYSQL\_ATTR\_INIT\_COMMAND' with pdo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424343/undefined-class-constant-mysql-attr-init-command-with-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a PHP 5.3.0 bug on Windows where MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND is not available. The PHP bug report is:

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47224

If you are experiencing this, please update your WAMP product to a version that uses PHP 5.3.1 or later version.