# PHP 5.4.9 Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to configure doctrine by following [this](http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine-orm-zf2-tutorial/#/24) tutorial and when I run that command: 
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema I get an error:

Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' in var/www/CommunicationApp/config/autoload/global.php on line 19

Here is the global.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Global Configuration Override
 *
 * You can use this file for overriding configuration values from modules, etc.
 * You would place values in here that are agnostic to the environment and not
 * sensitive to security.
 *
 * @NOTE: In practice, this file will typically be INCLUDED in your source
 * control, so do not include passwords or other sensitive information in this
 * file.
 */

return array(
  'db' => array(
     'driver'  => 'Pdo',
     'dsn'   => 'mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;host=localhost',
     'driver_options' => array(
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
     ),
 ),
 'service_manager' => array(
     'factories' => array(
         'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                 => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
     ),
 ),
);
```

I already uncomment the extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll in /usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini

Comment: Try namespacing it to the "root" namespace: `\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` (the backslash before PDO)

Comment: It didn't work, same error

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476106/undefined-class-constant-mysql-attr-init-command-in-mamp-using-php-5-4-4

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the PHP MySQL extension installed. On Ubuntu that would be:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]                       
  File mapping drivers must have a valid directory path, however the given pa  
  th [/var/www/CommunicationApp/module/CsnFileManager/config/../src/CsnFileMa  
  nager/Entity] seems to be incorrect!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with this PDO line, then first of all, I installed the php5-mysql package that Tim Fountain posted. The second step was remove the escape from the lines.

```
'driver_options' => array(
     PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
 ),
```

After both things, it worked!