# PDO : Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I uncommented the lines `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll 
extension=php_pdo.dll` in my php.ini file but I still got the error
`Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'` 
None of the previous answers worked for me what should I do ?

```
 $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
try 
{ $cnx = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password,$options); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{  die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
}
```

Comment: did you restart everything after making those changes? If not, then do. Those changes won't take effect until you restarted all services.

Comment: See also http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php *"Setting the connection character set to UTF-8 prior to PHP 5.3.6"* - and http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php and this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424343/undefined-class-constant-mysql-attr-init-command-with-pdo and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476106/undefined-class-constant-mysql-attr-init-command-in-mamp-using-php-5-4-4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059697/undefined-class-constant-mysql-attr-init-command-in-undefined-class-constant

Comment: Are u using Microsoft-IIS? If yes? Did you reboot your IIS after you uncommented the extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes I did still wont work, and I actually found it uncommented from the start.

Comment: have a look at the links I left you above.

Comment: did you set the extension_dir in php.ini? it should like: extension_dir = ".\ext"

Comment: @Paules I Changed `;extension_dir = "./"` to `extension_dir = "./ext"` and restart everything but I still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this one once..!

```
try 
{ 
$cnx = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{  die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
}
```

// need more

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
```

Rrefer once this :

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: I got this error `Failed to connect to the database: could not find driver`

Comment: what is the output when you do `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers);` ?

Comment: `Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'getAvailableDrivers' in `

Comment: Ye then your problem is in your php.ini. Your extension is not loaded properly. Is the extension located in a subfolder called ext in your php folder?

Comment: I only have php_pdo_mysql.dll

Comment: u have to give proper db name username and password