# Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' in Undefined class constant (PHP 5.5.3)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a config file that connects to a remote database, however i keep receiving an error that i don't know how to fix. In the earlier versions it was meant to be a bug but i assumed it would have been fixed by 5.5.3.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "registration";
$username = "databaseEditor";
$password = "yolo10";

// 1002 = MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

try
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username$
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo "File works";
?>
```

I keep receiving the error `"Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'"`. I have tried to use 1002 instead of 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' but then i end up with the error
`"syntax error, unexpected '1002' (T_LNUMBER)"` instead and i have also have installed the newest php-mysql extension.

Comment: from the example you gave, I can't see full declaration of $db can you edit it please?

Comment: Done, excuse the childish password.

Comment: What phpinfo() shows about PDO??

Comment: you didn't get me, you can leave username and pass empty, update line where you have `$db = new PDO...` because we can't see full line

Comment: Do you have pdo_mysql extension enabled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined class constant 'MYSQL\_ATTR\_INIT\_COMMAND' with pdo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424343/undefined-class-constant-mysql-attr-init-command-with-pdo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try editing your php.ini:

On a windows server you can add the following lines in your php.ini

```
 extension=php_pdo.dll
 extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

On a Linux server you can compile php with the following option --with-pdo-mysql

In your php.ini, add the following lines

```
 extension=pdo.so
 extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: If you feel that this asnwer help to solve your problem, don't forget to mark it as correct...cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

## On Ubuntu 14.04

### Install php5-mysql package

`sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

### If the above is already installed

`sudo php5enmod pdo`

`sudo php5enmod pdo_mysql`

### Restart Web Server

Answer (score 0):

The `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` constant is defined by the MySQL driver of the PDO extension. You most likely forgot to install either.

Once you install the appropriate extensions, you can forget about `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND`. The correct way to set the connection encoding is what you already do—the DSN parameter in the constructor:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username$
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Last but not least, your code seems to have plenty of syntax errors. You need to enable full error reporting in your php.ini file because these lines:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

... won't execute if the script can't even run.